# loop through an array of request data and then save each group request data

Tags: php, loops, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this script that will generate input fields dynamically

```
$(document).on("click", ".if_married_add_fields", function(e){
   $("#if_married_table tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="children[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Children name" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="type_of_delivery[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Type of delivery" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="date[]" class="form-control date_picker" placeholder="date" readonly required/></td></tr>');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

and then this table where the generated input fields will be placed

```
<table class="table-bordered table" style="min-height: 150px;" id="if_married_table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-align_center">Name of Child/Children</th>
                                        <th class="text-align_center">Type of Delivery</th>
                                        <th class="text-align_center">Dates</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

and in my table structure i have this:

```
id (auto increment, int, primary), children (varchar 250), type_of_delivery (varchar 250), date (varchar 250)
```

so if I'm going to loop the request data when saving and on saved, it should look like this in the database

1, children 1, type of delivery 1, 2015-10-10
2, children 2, type of delivery 2, 2015-10-11
3, children 3, type of delivery 3, 2015-10-12

assume I have added 3 rows with input field per column identity and then been save it unto the database successfully.

any ideas, clues, help, suggestion, to achieve it please?

Comment: you need to implode the relevant input field names within php i.e. implode(',',$_POST['children']); to convert the arrays to strings so you can store the data into the relevant database fields.

Comment: please take note that im using a framework called LARAVEL not a native PHP.

Comment: Laravel is written in PHP and it can use native PHP approaches.